# Order the Time Units on Y-axis + Chart Js

Tags: chart.js

I have time on Y-axis and dates on X-axis. I have built the chart using chart.js and my chart looks as below.

[image]

But, as you can see my Y-axis is in reversed order. I don't know how to fix it. Please assist.

Here is my js

```
var s1 = {
    label:'S1',
  borderColor: '#33b5e5',
  data: [
    { x: '2017-01-06 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 04:15:30' },
    { x: '2017-01-07 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 07:39:30' },
    { x: '2017-01-08 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 06:39:30' },
    { x: '2017-01-09 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 08:00:30' },
    { x: '2017-01-10 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 05:39:30' },
    { x: '2017-01-11 00:00:00', y: '2017-01-06 09:39:30' },
  ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',

  data: { datasets: [s1] },
  options: {
     legend: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        weight : 0 ,
         time: {
           unit:'day'
          }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        //type: 'linear',
        reverse: false,
         time: {
           unit:'hour'
          },
          ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '380px';
chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '700px';
```

Please find the full code snippet in below link. 
https://jsfiddle.net/sjabiulla/3d1tpwhy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart.js 2.8.0 [adds `reverse` support to time scales](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5927), although this doesn't appear to be documented anywhere except the [release notes](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.8.0). Move `reverse` into the tick configuration and it should fix the problem:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    reverse: true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}]
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var s1 = {
  label: 'S1',
  borderColor: '#33b5e5',
  data: [{
      x: '2017-01-06 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 04:15:30'
    },
    {
      x: '2017-01-07 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 07:39:30'
    },
    {
      x: '2017-01-08 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 06:39:30'
    },
    {
      x: '2017-01-09 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 08:00:30'
    },
    {
      x: '2017-01-10 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 05:39:30'
    },
    {
      x: '2017-01-11 00:00:00',
      y: '2017-01-06 09:39:30'
    },
  ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [s1]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        weight: 0,
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour'
        },
        ticks: {
          reverse: true,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '380px';
chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '700px';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you probably help me building Bar chart with the same data that I have for line chart. I have tried, but it's not working as expected. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869758/bar-not-showing-bar-chart-chart-js